# Rollup replaces node modules imports with relative paths

Tags: node.js, npm, rollupjs

I'm having a problem with Rollup and the rollup-plugin-node-resolve.

If I have an import of this kind:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

it gets converted to:

```
import _ from '../node_modules/lodash/lib/index.js';
```

This breaks the bundle when I try to use it inside a project which uses Webpack because the `node_modules` folder is not child of the folder of my Rollup-bundled package obviously (because npm flats the dependencies).

I am already defining all the `node_modules` as `external`.

This is my relevant config:

```
{
  entry: 'dist/components-index.js',
  external: id => id.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0,
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.json'],
    }),
    commonjs({
      namedExports: { '../xxx-styles/lib/index.js': ['common', 'dark', 'light' ] },
    }),
  ],
}
```

How can I make the build keep the node modules import preserve the absolute paths? I'd like to keep them as I write, so that node.js/webpack/wathever can resolve the imports properly.

Answer (score 7):

You want to mark `lodash` as external *before* it gets resolved:

```js
{
  entry: 'dist/components-index.js',
  external: ['lodash', ...],
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.json'],
    }),
    commonjs({
      namedExports: { '../xxx-styles/lib/index.js': ['common', 'dark', 'light' ] },
    }),
  ],
}
```

A good way to mark all dependencies as external is to use the `"dependencies"` field in your package.json file:

```js
// rollup.config.js
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import pkg from './package.json';

export default {
  entry: 'dist/components-index.js',
  external: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies),
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.json'],
    }),
    commonjs({
      namedExports: { '../xxx-styles/lib/index.js': ['common', 'dark', 'light' ] },
    }),
  ],
}
```

Since you're marking everything in `node_modules` as external, I would recommend not bothering with the `resolve` plugin — if you're explicit about file extensions (which Rollup will probably insist on in the near future, to increase compatibility with native module loaders in browsers), you won't need it.

Comment: I'm already using `external: id => id.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0,` to mark all the node_modules dependencies as external, why isn't it enough?

Comment: Because the file has been resolved by that point — it doesn't get 'unresolved'. The purpose is to allow you to specify that particular files in *your source code* shouldn't be bundled, for whatever reason — for third-party packages you should exclude the ID pre-resolution.

Comment: I don't quite get it.. if I put a console log in the `external` function it returns the path including `node_modules`, so it should return `true` and get excluded according to the documentation?

Comment: Also, with your suggestion, if I import `react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup` it will not be detected as external

Comment: It does get excluded! But the path has been resolved already. Just don't include the `resolve` plugin — it's really easy. If you insist on using resolve, then do something like `id => id !== myEntryFile && id[0] !== '.'`

Comment: I'm saying it doesn't get excluded because Rollup tells me that it did exclude it because it couldn't resolve it. While the other packages don't throw any error

Comment: Okay, yeah, you would need to add `react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup` to `external`.

Comment: This is a nightmare 

Comment: Look, why are you using `resolve`? Seems like all your problems would be solved if you just didn't use that

Comment: Because all the code base is using already this convention and the team is happy with it. Honestly I would expect my custom "external " function to work as is, I'm going to send a PR against the doc to explain that the "external " function isn't meant for what everybody think...